# Powershell - How Do I Pass Command Line Arguments to a Function in a Module?

Tags: powershell, command-line, parameters, arguments

I've written a PowerShell module to show help when the user requests it with a command line parameter like **-show help-topic**. I import it into the main script with this statement:

```
Import-Module Help-Module -ArgumentList $args
```

Scripts call a module function like this:

```
Show-Help $args
```

This is the called function:

```
function Show-Help {
<#
.SYNOPSIS
Looks for command line arguments indicating user requested help, and if they are present, displays the
requested help.
.OUTPUTS
$true if one or more help requests were found and answered, else $false.
Throws an error if a help request was malformed.
#>
   Write-Debug "Inside Show-Help"
   if ([string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($args)) {                     # If no arguments
      return $false                                               # Nothing to do
   }
   if ($args.Length -gt 0 -and $args[0] -eq "-help") {            # If just a generic help request
      Show-ScriptOverview                                         # Show script overview
      return $true                                                # And we’re done
   }                                                              # Otherwise
   foreach ($argument in $args) {                                 # Examine each argument
      Write-Host "Argument type is $($argument.getType())"
      $argarray = $argument.split(' ')                  
      if ($argarray.length -eq 2 -and $argarray[0] -eq "-show") { # If it’s a “show” request
         switch ($topic = $($argarray[1])) {                      # What is user requesting?
            default {throw "Sorry, we don’t what '$topic' means"} # Unless we don’t recognize it
         }
         return $true
      }
   }
}
```

It outputs **Argument type is System.Object[]**

Then it fails on the call to `$argument.split(' ')` with this message:

**Method invocation failed because [System.Object[]] does not contain a method named 'split'**

How can I pass command line arguments to a module function in a data type that I can get string values from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `Show-Help $args` with:

```bash
Show-Help @args
```

That is, use [splatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Splatting) in order to pass the arguments that your script received through to the `Show-Help` function.

Note that for the purpose of relaying arguments it is irrelevant whether your function is defined in a module or not.

---

As for **what you tried**:

> `Show-Help $args`

passes the [automatic `$args` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#args) as a *single* argument that is an *array* to `Show-Help`, which explains why the - redefined inside `Show-Help` - `$args` variable saw an *array* in its first - and only - element, `$args[0]`